# Cucumber Exception Failed to create directory

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, pom.xml, file-permissions

When I run MainRunner class in response I get error message in console like below. I did set permissions for folder.

[image]

Here is my step class:

```
package CucumberFramework.steps;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;

import cucumber.api.java.en.When;



public class LoginSteps {

@Given("^User navigate to stackoverflow webstie$")

public void user_navigate_to_stackoverflow_webstie() throws Throwable {

   System.out.println("user_navigate_to_stackoverflow_webstie");

}



@Given("^User clicks on the login button$")

public void user_clicks_on_the_login_button() throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("user_clicks_on_the_login_button");

}



@Given("^User enters valid username$")

public void user_enters_valid_username() throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_enters_valid_username");

}



@Given("^User enters valid password$")

public void user_enters_valid_password() throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_enters_valid_password");

}

@When("^User clicks again on the login button$")

public void user_clicks_again_on_the_login_button() throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_clicks_again_on_the_login_button");

}



@Then("^User should be taken to the sucsfull login page$")

public void user_should_be_taken_to_the_sucsfull_login_page() throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_should_be_taken_to_the_sucsfull_login_page");

}

@Given("^User navigate to stackoverflow webstie(\\d+)$")

public void user_navigate_to_stackoverflow_webstie2(int arg1) throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_navigate_to_stackoverflow_webstie2");

}



@Given("^User clicks on the login button(\\d+)$")

public void user_clicks_on_the_login_button2(int arg1) throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_clicks_on_the_login_button2");

}



@Given("^User enters valid username(\\d+)$")

public void user_enters_valid_username2(int arg1) throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_enters_valid_username2");

}



@Given("^User enters valid password(\\d+)$")

public void user_enters_valid_password2(int arg1) throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_enters_valid_password2");

}



@When("^User clicks again on the login button(\\d+)$")

public void user_clicks_again_on_the_login_button2(int arg1) throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_clicks_again_on_the_login_button2");

}



@Then("^User should be taken to the sucsfull login page(\\d+)$")

public void user_should_be_taken_to_the_sucsfull_login_page2(int arg1) throws Throwable {

System.out.println("user_should_be_taken_to_the_sucsfull_login_page2");

}

}
```

I have also looked at permissions for the target folder and have ensured permissions is granted for all users. I'm on Windows 10 Pro. I also try to run Eclipse in administrator mode that didn't help as well.

This is my Pom.xml
[https://pastebin.com/ad2qyGRH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLOv4.png)

I have also tried the following:

running: Eclipse menu Project > Clean...

[image]

But no joy. Does anyone know what could be causing this please?

Kind regards

Comment: Could you check that `target/cucumber` is not a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have found, it seems that the `plugin` object is trying to create 2 directories called "cucumber" when what you want is for the object to create **a directory and a file** called cucumber. This is what your object looks like:

```
plugin = {
    "pretty", 
    "html:target/cucumber", //this is telling cucumber to create a folder called cucumber
    "json:target/cucumber", //this is also telling cucumber to create a folder called cucumber 
                            //even though you just need a file called cucumber.json
    "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter: target/report.html" 
    //there is an unnecessary white space before "target" that is causing another issue
}
```

---

What you are trying to do is:

```
plugin = {
    "pretty", 
    "html:target/cucumber", //create a folder called cucumber
    "json:target/cucumber.json", 
    //Notice the corresponding file extension (.json) telling cucumber to create a file
    "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"
    //Notice I remove the white space at :target/report.html
}
```

Now the code is creating one **folder** called cucumber (this will hold a basic webpage that will display test results) and a **file** called cucumber.json (this will be the same test results but in json format)

***Don't forget to remove that white space!***
That white space then creates a separate folder called " target" (starting with a blank space) and that puts the report.html file in there instead of with the rest of the reporting artifacts.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The exception `cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory ...` happen, when a file with the name of output directory (`target/cucumber`) already exists.

Assume following structure

```
src/test/java/runner/TestRunner.java
pom.xml
```

**pom.xml** dependencies

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.cucumber>2.0.0</version.cucumber>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
package runner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "html:target/cucumber" })
public class TestRunner {
}
```

steps to reproduce

```
$ mvn clean test-compile
$ echo "some text" > target/cucumber
```

now as the file `target/cucumber` exists, run the test

```
$ mvn test
```

it fails with

```
Caused by: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory /tmp/cuke.test/target/cucumber
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.HTMLFormatter.createReportFileOutputStream(HTMLFormatter.java:520)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.HTMLFormatter.createJsOut(HTMLFormatter.java:510)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.HTMLFormatter.<init>(HTMLFormatter.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Based on the line numbers in the above stacktrace and in the screenshot from the OP. It seems the OP uses a Cucumber version `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Because the method `reportFileOutputStream` was renamed in class `HTMLFormatter` to `createReportFileOutputStream` (SHA1: [486b82cb9](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/commit/486b82cb9#diff-06848ed0e2f171c1ff3bc712875edafeL504)). Which was before Cucumber version `2.0.0` was released.

**edit:** Some more detailed explanation. The main problem is that the plugins try to created a directory entry with the same name `target/cucumber`.

- html - will create a **directory** `target/cucumber`
- json - will create a **file** `target/cucumber`

As mentioned above the exception `Failed to create directory` is thrown, when a directory should be created and a file with the same already exists.

It can reproduced with following `CucumberOptions` in `TestRunner.java`.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"json:target/cucumber", "html:target/cucumber"})
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: \
    java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory /.../target/cucumber
```

*note:* In the OP's code the order of the plugins is not `json - html` it's `html - json`. Hence the above snippet used only the `html` plugin and created the file `target/cucumber` before running the test.

Using the plugins in the same order as shown in the OP's screenshot throws a different exception.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber"})
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \
    target/cucumber (Is a directory)
```

Based on the steps used to reproduce the collision the plugins order and the exception in the screenshot do not match.

Most probably changing the output filename of the json plugin (`"json:target/cucumber.json"`) will solve the issue.

Comment: Could you please provide a solution to this problem? Thanks

Comment: @Ryan I added a more detailed explanation and the most probable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when plugins write to colliding paths.
For example: `json:target/cucumber/report.json, html:target/cucumber`.

To fix the issue, ensure that the paths do no conflict or collide.
For example: `json:target/cucumber/report.json, html:target/cucumber/report.html`. Note that `report.json` and `report.html` are both files (with extensions). If you make at least one of them a directory (without an extension), an exception will be thrown at runtime.